# PHP: How do you get print_r or var_dump to output a binary string with zeros?

Tags: php

I have a binary string obtained via `file_get_contents`. It has zeros in it. `var_dump` lists the correct length but stops output at the first zero.  How do I dump the entire binary string?

Comment: Binary strings are generally not intended for consumption with human eyeballs, will render differently depending on what renders them, and will frequently "break" whatever they are rendered into. If you just need to output to verify byte values for debugging, then Karl's suggestion below is most apt, but if you have other reasons you'll need to put those into your question so that we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: What is it that you want to "see" in the binary data?

Comment: \x00 where the zeros are.  But the workaround is marked in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a binary string with zeros, you can use the `bin2hex` function to convert the binary data to hexadecimal representation. This will give you a string that you can output with `echo`, `print_r`, or `var_dump`, and it will include all the data, including zeros.

```
$binaryString = file_get_contents('your_file_path');
$hexString = bin2hex($binaryString);
var_dump($hexString);
```